# dll export function to ctypes

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

## Background

I have some functions which are written in C++, which require high real-time performance. I want to quickly export these functions as dynamic link library to be exposed to Python so that I could do some high level programming.

In these functions, in order to simply usage, I use PyList_New in <Python.h> to collect some intermedia data. But I met some errors.

## Code Example

I found the core problem is that I CAN'T event export a python object. After compiling the source to dll and use ctypes to load it, result shows

```
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000008
```

C++ code:

```
#include <Python.h>


#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define DLL_EXPORT  __declspec( dllexport )
#else
#define DLL_EXPORT
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

DLL_EXPORT PyObject *test3() {
    PyObject* ptr = PyList_New(10);
    return ptr;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Python test code:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import ctypes

    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(LIB_DLL)
    
    test3 = lib.test3
    test3.argtypes = None
    test3.restype = ctypes.py_object
    
    print(test3())
```

## Environment Config

Clion with Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Community, and the arch is amd64.

I know that, the right way is to use the recommanded method to wrap C++ source using Python/C Api to a module, but it seems that I have to code a lot. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

`ctypes` is normally for calling "regular" C functions, not Python C API functions, but it can be done.  You must use `PyDLL` to load a function that uses Python, as it won't release the GIL (global intepreter lock) required to be held when using Python functions.  Your code as shown is invalid, however, because it doesn't populate the list it creates (using OP code as test.c):

```py
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> lib = PyDLL('./test')
>>> lib.test3.restype=py_object
>>> lib.test3()
[<NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>]
```

Instead, write a C or C++ function normally:

test.cpp

```cpp
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define DLL_EXPORT  __declspec( dllexport )
#else
#define DLL_EXPORT
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

DLL_EXPORT int* create(int n) {
    auto p = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        p[i] = i;
    return p;
}

DLL_EXPORT void destroy(int* p) {
    delete [] p;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

test.py

```py
from ctypes import *

lib = CDLL('./test')
lib.create.argtypes = c_int,
lib.create.restype = POINTER(c_int)
lib.destroy.argtypes = POINTER(c_int),
lib.destroy.restype = None

p = lib.create(5)
print(p) # pointer to int
print(p[:5]) # convert to list...pointer doesn't have length so slice.
lib.destroy(p) # free memory
```

Output:

```
<__main__.LP_c_long object at 0x000001E094CD9DC0>
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by myself. Just change  to Release and all the problems are solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).